# Get COUNT of DISTINCT Months Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get count of distinct months between two dates. However, I am getting a missing right parenthesis error. As with many of us I like using dual table on the fly.

Here is the query. Can you please advise what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT(TRUNC BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2020-07-07','YYYY-MM-DD'),'MM'))
FROM dual
```

Comment: How about `months_between`?

Comment: thank you that does work. But the inquisitive me would like to know is my approach wrong or can it be tweaked to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting isn't the right tool for this really; your `trunc()` is missing its opening parenthesis, but `BETWEEN` is a condition not a function, so that is also wrong.

Oracle has [the `months_between()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MONTHS_BETWEEN.html) to do this; it will give a fractional value, so you can use `floor()` to get the number of complete months, or `ceil()` to get the number of partial months:

```
select
  months_between (date '2020-07-07', date '2019-08-01') as result1,
  floor(months_between (date '2020-07-07', date '2019-08-01')) as result2,
  ceil(months_between (date '2020-07-07', date '2019-08-01')) as result3
from dual;

   RESULT1    RESULT2    RESULT3
---------- ---------- ----------
11.1935484         11         12
```

If you wanted to list the months then you could use a hierarchcal query or recursive subquery factoring, e.g.:

```
with rcte (this_month, last_month) as (
  select trunc(date '2019-08-01', 'MM'), trunc(date '2020-07-07', 'MM')
  from dual
  union all
  select r.this_month + interval '1' month, r.last_month
  from rcte r
  where r.this_month < r.last_month
)
select this_month
from rcte
order by this_month;

THIS_MONTH
----------
2019-08-01
2019-09-01
2019-10-01
...
2020-06-01
2020-07-01
```

and count those instead:

```
with rcte (this_month, last_month) as (
  select trunc(date '2019-08-01', 'MM'), trunc(date '2020-07-07', 'MM')
  from dual
  union all
  select r.this_month + interval '1' month, r.last_month
  from rcte r
  where r.this_month < r.last_month
)
select count(this_month) as result
from rcte;

RESULT
------
    12
```

but that's more work than you need to do if you only want that number.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8fc3328811a18160482351385918c864)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is incorrect and It is better to use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` as it takes care of everything i.e. different number of days in the month and etc.

You can use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` as follows:

```
SELECT 
MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE('2020-07-07','YYYY-MM-DD'),TO_DATE('2019-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

months_between may not be solution for all scenarios; example:

SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE('2021-12-20','YYYY-MM-DD'),TO_DATE('2022-01-05','YYYY-MM-DD')) FROM dual
will result is 0.5 months; but actually both dec and jan are used in query and expected result may 2.

So using above example of with function will provide correct result no matter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).